# Silverstripe 3.4 Module to extend image is not creating the database columns

Tags: php, image, module, silverstripe

i am sure i am missing something obvious, but this is my first attempt to actually create my own module, and the documentation just doesn't seem to be doing any good for me.

The issue is that the dependency on this new field i added seems to be working, as i get the SQL error saying that it can't find the field in the Image Table, but /dev/build is not creating the new column. I even tried manually adding the column, and then everything seems to work fine -- but this will not help for installing it onto my colleague's computers, or onto any other site.

Here are the basic files as they stand (some of the names have been changed a little, but the gist is still the same):

**/tinyimage-uploads/_config.php**

```
<?php
Object::add_extension('Image', 'TinyImageExtension');
```

**/tinyimage-uploads/code/TinyImageExtension.php**

```
<?php

class TinyImageExtension extends DataExtension {

  private static $db = array(
    'Compressed' => 'Boolean'
  );

}
```

There are tons of methods i need to put into this, specifically onAfterUpload() -- but i can't even get this one field created. I have tried basing this off of Focuspoint [Link to Github](https://github.com/jonom/silverstripe-focuspoint) -- as this is also installed on the site, but i am just having no luck with this. All the documentation tells me that this should be enough, and some tells me that no static methods are allowed in DataExtension... but that seems to work fine in many of the other modules we have installed.

Please help, this is driving me crazy and i don't know if it just means there is something wrong with my Apache or if i am just missing some basic files for modules and just not having any luck finding the right documentation to get me started.

Comment: Did you run `dev/build/?flush` after you added the extension? Did dev/build end with "done" or is anything else making problems?

Comment: Yeah, i tried everything that made sense, dev/build, dev/build?flush, even restarting my computer in case something in my Apache had screwed up, still no luck :/ still showing "database build complete" every time, even though when i try to access any page it comes up with the SQL error telling me the "Image.Compressed" column doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing/deleting the line 
`Object::add_extension('Image', 'TinyImageExtension');` 
from `/tinyimage-uploads/_config.php` and leave it as an empty PHP file and instead do this.

Create a new yml file at 
`tinyimage-uploads/_config/_config.yml` and add your image extension to it like this

```
---
Name: tinyimage-uploads
After:
  - 'framework/*'
  - 'cms/*'
---

#Custom Image Extension
Image:
  extensions:
    - TinyImageExtension
```

Finally run `dev/build` and confirm that the `Compressed` Boolean data column has been created in your `Image` database table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, i have tried that a couple of times today, gave it one more go and sadly the Image.Compressed column is still not being created...

Comment: @EEKim Can you add a text representation of the folder and the files in it you created for this module? That way we can see if anything is missing

Comment: Sure, i was attempting to make it as basic as possible for me to get an understanding of a boilerplate version, here's the file structure:

tinyimage-uploads/
> _config/
 >> config.yml (tried _config.yml too)
> code/
 >> TinyImageExtension.php
> _config.php

Comment: dev/build only creates the column in DB when it finishes without errors. So please check if it ends with "done". If not something else causes it to fail.

Comment: The last line on my dev/build has been "Database build completed!" every time, it doesn't look like it's run in to any errors

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is wrong with the code from what I've seen. You can look in the database columns on the Image table as the `Compressed` boolean field column might already be there.

Comment: That's kind of the same boat i'm in which makes this all the more frustrating, it all looks fine, but for some reason just isn't creating the column... i did check several times in my localhost, the column isn't there unless i create it manually. Not sure where to go to debug this :/

Comment: Update:: This code does work when put into a different database, which i guess is progress at least, but i still have no idea why this one particular database would be fussy -- is there an issue by chance if there are several backups of the database that start with the same string?

Comment: @EEKim Try to Create a `silverstripe-cache` in your project root folder and run the `dev/build` task. If you already have a silverstripe-cache directory in your project, then delete that and create it again. Doing that should reset any code files that are refusing to update

Comment: I hadn't thought of that one, sadly it still didn't work, but i will add that to my list of things to debug in the future :P thank you